# How to use chunk() in Laravel for progress and failure updates?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, lumen

Laravel Eloquent Model called **ProductModel** that references a table that contains a large number of rows (*i.e. 500,000*). Each row contains a **product_id** that calls the function `isValid()` which either continues the loop or breaks it.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#chunking-results

The example I have created to illustrate the problem: (*UPDATED 16/03/22*)

```
$log = array();
$log[] = ['Checking products...'];

$count = 0;
$chunks = 5000;
$total = ProductModel::count();

ProductModel::chunk($chunks, function ($products) uses (&$count, $log, $total) {
    foreach ($products as $row) {
        $this->isValid($row->product_id);
        $count++;
    }
    $log[] = '[Success] Completed '. $count .' of '. $total .' records';
});
```

Each record of the loop is then stored in the array `$log`.

```
[Success] Completed 5,000 of 20,000 records
[Success] Completed 10,000 of 20,000 records
[Success] Completed 15,000 of 20,000 records
[Success] Completed 20,000 of 20,000 records
```

If an `Exception` is thrown from `$this->isValid()` the array `$log` should contain something similar to the following:

```
Checking products...
[Success] Completed 5,000 of 20,000 records
[Failed] Completed 7,402 of 20,000 records
```

Comment: Declare `$count = 0` outside the loop and then as you say you need to do `use (&$count, $log)`  (not sure if you need to pass the log by reference since you are only appending to it rather than changing its whole value)

Comment: What exactly do you need in `$log` when `$this->isValid()` throws?